# Why is this function valid to calculate modular pow value?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have seen this function in [SRM 573's solution here:](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+573#WolfPack)

```
long modPow(long x, long y)
{
    //Caculates x raised to the y-power modulo MOD
    //in O(log(y)) time by using  repeated squaring
    long r = 1;
    while(y > 0){
        if( (y&1) != 0) {
            r = (r * x) % MOD;
        }
        x = (x * x)%MOD;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

But I am confused by this function to **calculate the modular value of `x^y%MOD`**;
why is `x = (x * x)%MOD;` needed in the function?
It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: It's an optimization.

Imagine that x is 2 and MOD is 3. Note that the only thing x is used for is multiplying r by x.

Now imagine that we square x. x*x = 4. Now, r*4 % 3 is going to equal 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... for r = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... oh! it's the same as if x was 1. In fact, if you set x to x*x %3 instead of just x*x, you get the same result.

But what about the next step? 4*4 = 16, %3 = 1. 1*1 = 1, %3 also = 1. So, we're stuck at the same residual no matter if we mod off the operation early or late or never.

Answer (score 1):

At each pass through the loop shown below, a low-order bit is shifted off of `y`, where `y` starts out as the exponent that base `x` is to be raised to.

```
long r = 1;
while(y > 0){
    if( (y&1) != 0) {
        r = (r * x) % MOD;
    }
    x = (x * x)%MOD;
    y >>= 1;
}
```

For example, if `y = 0b1101`, or 13 decimal, then `xʸ = x¹³ = x¹⁺⁴⁺⁸ = x·x⁴·x⁸` and the `if( (y&1) != 0) r = (r * x) % MOD` part will multiply `r` by `x` on the first, third, and fourth passes, when the current value of `x` is the first, fourth, and eighth power of the original value.

Note that because `(a·b) mod p ≡ ((a mod p)·(b mod p)) mod p`, the `mod` function can be applied after every multiplication.  Applying it that frequently minimizes the required number of bits for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating a little on @jwpat7 's answer, let's think about why

`(x % MOD)*(x % MOD) ≡ (x*x) % MOD`.

We can always write `x` as `x = n*MOD + r` for some naturals `n` and `r` with `r < MOD` (if also `x < MOD` that implies `x = r` and `n = 0`).

Now, we always get `x % MOD = (n*MOD + r) % MOD = r`, and therefore we get

`(x % MOD)*(x % MOD) = r * r`.

On the other hand, consider what `(x*x) % MOD` evaluates to:

`x*x = (n*MOD + r)*(n*MOD +r) = n*n*MOD*MOD + 2*n*r*MOD + r*r`, and therefore we get `(x*x) % MOD = (n*n*MOD*MOD + 2*n*r*MOD + r*r) % MOD = r*r`

This is why Patashu said that it doesn't matter whether you apply the modulo operator early or late, because the remainder `r` is all that is actually relevant to the modulo operation and is also the only thing that carries over to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the modular part for a while, and ask yourself, “How can I efficiently calculate x^n for n a positive integer?” You can calculate x^2 with one multiplication: x * x.  You can calculate x^3 with two multiplications: x^3 = x * x^2.  You can calculate x^4 with two multiplications: x^4 = x^2^2 = x^2 * x^2.  You can calculate x^n in general with this recursion:

```
For even n = 2*m, x^n = (x^2)^m.

For odd n = 2*m + 1, x^n = x * (x^m)^2.
```

So, we get x^10 as:

```
x^10 = (x^2)^5
     = x^2 * (x^4)*2
```

Compute x^2, x^4, x^8, x^10, for 4 multiplications.

Note that this is a good general method, but it is not guaranteed to be the most efficient.  Try x^15, for example.  This method gives you x * (x^2)^7 = x * x^2 * (x^2)^6 = x * x^2 ^ (x^4)^3 = x ^ x^2 * x^4 * (x^4)^2.  You compute x^2, x^4, x^8, and then x * x^2 * x^4 * x^8, for 6 multiplications.  Faster is

```
y = x^3 = x * x^2, 2 multiplications.
x^15 = y^5 = y * (y^2)^2, 3 more multiplications,
This is a total of 5 multiplications.
```

In fact, for an exponent n, define an addition chain as a sequence of numbers starting at 1 and ending at n, where each number in the list is the sum of 2 previous numbers in the sequence (and you can repeat).

The algorithm for 15 gives

1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 15.

The shorter one is

1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 15.

It turns out to be computationally hard to find the shortest addition chain ending at a target number.